# Why logic of diag(s)*C*diag(s); in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, this seems to be more of algo question but can someone explain the logic of `Sigma_0=diag(s)*C*diag(s)`?

```
s=.07*ones(N,1);
Sigma_0=diag(s)*C*diag(s);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It scales all the columns by 0.07 and then scales the rows by 0.07.

However, this is exactly the same as:

```
  Sigma_0=C * 0.07^2;
```

If `s` were something other than a scalar times a vector of ones, this would scale the rows and columns each by some numbers.  For instance, if `C` was 4x4 and if `s=[1 2 3 4]` then `diag(s)*C` would scale the first row by 1, the second row by 2 etc.  Similarly, `C*diag(s)` would scale the first column by 1, the second column by 2 etc.

Comment: Wow. Best explanation yet. Thanks Chris!